# How to write "gate of worlds" in Latin?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, contemporary-latin

I know that the Latin words for "gate" and "world" are *porta* and *mundus*, respectively. However, while I know how to write "Gate of the World" in Latin (*Porta Mundi*) since both "gate" and "world" are singular in the English phrase, I'm not sure about doing so for "Gate of World**s**".

Do I write it as *Porta Mundorum*, using the plural genitive of *mundus*? Or do I use the adjective *mundanus* and, following the example of "Star Wars" being rendered as *Bella Stellaria* in Latin (where *stellaria* is in the neuter nominative plural case), write it as *Porta Mundana*? Or are both approaches correct? Or are they both wrong?

PS: The phrase "Gate of Worlds" is supposed to emphasize the fact that the gate in question connects **several** worlds together.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only one of those options is correct. Let us start with *porta mundorum*. This translates to "gate of world," which is just what you are seeking, as it is a singular gate belonging to multiple worlds.

Since that checks out, let's take a look at the other one. *Porta mundana* literally translates to "earthly port." Here, it is a single port belonging to a presumably single earth. I understand the idea of mirroring "Star Wars"/*Bella Stellaria*, but this is an incorrect correlation in ideas. In *Bella Stellaria*, *bella* is actually a plural noun (from *bellum*). *Stellaria*, or "stellar," is an adjective modifying *bella*. This plurality reflects the fact that it is "Star Wars" (multiple wars) and not "War of Stars" (multiple stars). So if you were to pluralize *porta mundana* to *portae mundanae*, you would have "Earthly gates" (multiple gates instead of multiple worlds"). Leaving it in the singular doesn't work either. This thus rules out this option.

In summary, ***porta mundorum*** is perfectly acceptable.

---

Perhaps you would like something that translates closer to "gate between worlds" then I would also suggest *porta inter mundos*.

Answer (score 5):

I agree with Sam K that *porta mundana* is simply an "earthly/wordly gate", and therefore not suitable for your use.
The genitive is possible, but let me offer another option.
If you want to use an adjective — which is often an idiomatic choice in Latin — you might consider *intermundanus*.

This adjective is not attested in classical Latin (as far as I can tell), but I think there is sufficient precedent for using the prefix *inter-* productively.
For example, we have adjectives like [*intermenstruus*](http://latinlexicon.org/definition.php?p1=2029973) and [*intermuralis*](http://latinlexicon.org/definition.php?p1=2030001).

Therefore one option would be ***porta intermundana***, which I might translate as "interwordly gate", for the lack of a better word.