# How to correctly say Star Wars in Latin?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, contemporary-latin

I know that the nouns are *stella* and *bellum*, but I think the translation should in spirit be closer to *stellar wars* or something similar.

Comment: Related: https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/5010/how-to-write-gate-of-worlds-in-latin/

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Joonas' answer is right on grammar, but since we're not talking about a single star, an adjective based on *sidus* would have better semantics.  I'd go with *Bella Siderea*.

Familiarity with modern Romance languages is not an unmixed blessing when translating into Latin.  Often Latin has multiple words in the same semantic field with different shades of meaning, only one of which survived into the Romance languages.

Because number markings on adjectives just show concordance with the noun, there is no way to get around the number implications of *stellaria* vs *siderea*.  *Bella Stellaria* means star wars in the sense of wars *about a particular star*; only *Bella Siderea* means wars fought *among the stars* (in the sense of out in space, in remote places).  Note that modern astronomical lexis in English retains this distinction at least to some extent--*stellar wind* is produced by a particular star (i.e., each produces its own), but *sidereal time* is time as measured by referencing the stars collectively.

Comment: This has the added benefit of being a classically attested word!

Comment: I think you're going too far by saying that *stellaria* is an incorrect translation. Regarding English usage, "stellar cluster," "stellar nursery," and "stellar parallax" are counterexamples. Regarding Latin usage, I'm not sure why you think it could only refer to a particular star: consider *famularis*, *columbarius*, etc., which all can refer to one or many *famuli*, *columbi*, etc.

Comment: @brianpck When there is an established alternative with the right semantics, choosing the other one suggests a different meaning.  *Sidus* and *stella* have an established contrast; you don't cite similar situations with your Latin examples.  Regarding the English terms, which aren't strictly relevant, for the first the correct English phrase is "star cluster", for the third parallax is a property of each star individually, just as much as mass and luminosity are.

Comment: The contrast, as I understand it, is between "star" and "constellation." Either can be plural, i.e. "stars" and "constellations." I'm not sure why you think *stellaris* can only refer to a singular star.

Comment: *Stella* can be plural, but *stellaris* being marked as plural just means it modifies a plural noun.  But if you mean something common to stars rather than specific to each star, then you need *siderea* rather than *strllaria*.

Comment: I understand that's your claim. I just don't see any reason behind it. If anything, "sidereus" seems wholly inappropriate for stars that *aren't* constellations.

Answer (score 16):

Indeed, you cannot use a plain noun as an attribute in Latin the way you can in English.
Instead of "Star Wars" you have to say "Wars of Stars" or "Stellar Wars".
Adjectives are a very natural choice in Latin (whereas I would be tempted to choose genitives in Romance languages).

*Bellum* is indeed good for "war".
It is a matter of taste whether you choose plural; not all official translations of the franchise do so.
The adjective from *stella* is *stellaris* and corresponds well to the English "stellar".

My translation suggestions are:

> ***Bella Stellaria*** (plural)
>   ***Bellum Stellare*** (singular)

The singular sounds better to me, but either is valid and readily understandable, at least now at the time of the premiere of Episode IX.

Both *stella* and *sidus* are good starting points for "star".
I would advice against interpreting words too narrowly in contexts like this — the original English title is not all that descriptive literally either, as stars actually play almost no role in the stories.
The way I see it, "star" is just a more poetic way of saying "space".
Both *stella* and *sidus* work well in this respect.
Efficient communication is a part of good use of language and *stella* resembles many star-words in other languages more closely, so it helps make the name more recognizable.

As brianpck comments below, *Stella Bellaria* has the benefit of sounding nice due to the repeated element *-ella-*.

Some might argue that the adjective *stellaris* is not a classically attested word.
While that is true to my knowledge, there are two good reasons why it does not matter much:
(1) not all Latin needs to be classical and (2) the word *stella* and many derivatives in *-aris* are attested, so *stellaris* is valid classical Latin to me although the word itself does not appear.

Comment: Latin wikipedia agrees with the plural, and Italian ("guerre stellari") is also plural. Strangely (judging from Wikipedia), French, German, Greek, and Spanish all seem to favor "war [sing.] of the stars [pl.]"--or, in the case of Spanish, "de las galaxias"

Comment: @brianpck Huh.  The Spanish name implies that there's more than one galaxy involved?

Comment: It was a tough choice between Bella Stellaria and Bella Siderea, but I will go with yours as that seems to be much more common and on Wikipedia too.

Comment: @alekdimi It's more common because it's more familiar from cognates in modern languages, not because it's correct.  It's like a native German speaker using "good" as an adverb in English just because "gut" works like that in German

Comment: @alekdimi And a check of Lewis and Short confirms that *stellaria* (and also for its other inflections) is not even attested as a word in classical Latin.

Comment: If you insist on *stella* I suppose you could try a locative to keep it classical (*bella stellis*).  That strains the locative, but it still sounds better to me than a genitive.   But even with the locative *bella sideribus* is better, as being less likely to roast the combatants alive. :)

Comment: @CMonsour I'd hardly think that a post-classical usage would discount this as a good answer (unless the question were, "How would Cicero say *Star Wars*?"). One point in favor of *Bella Stellaria* is that, by some linguistic luck, it reproduce pretty exactly the similar sound: *S**tar** W**ar**s* vs. *B**ell**a St**ell**aria*.

Comment: Even so, *Bella Stellaria* would refer to wars about a particular star, not wars out among the stars generally.  I'm sure you've seen *Star Wars*.  Which is an accurate description? :)

Comment: You have changed my mind, I have updated my chosen answer.

Comment: @brianpck "Star Wars" rhymes with "Are Ores", at least to me, so not as close as the spelling alone suggests.

Comment: I don't see how resemblance of the wrong word in Latin to the right word in other languages is a reason to suggest the wrong word, especially for someone who professes to care whether people get unfortunate tattoos...

Comment: @CMonsour I think it is a very strong statement to say that *stella* is wrong. Recognizability is one of the arguments I present, and I certainly would not use that to excuse a wrong word. But I do sincerely think that *stella* is valid (as is *sidus*) for this use, and I did write a whole paragraph about translating "star".

Answer (score 7):

The world has already chosen the translation (whether it's right or not). [Wikipedia](https://la.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars) calls it "Bella Stellaria". Some fans agree:

[image]

Comment: Gives a whole new meaning to "The Empire Strikes Back", err, I mean "Iterum Imperii Oppugnationes" :-)

Comment: Some random nobody who knows how to use Google Translate and post to Wikipedia is not "the world". See the answer by C Monsour for why this translation is wrong.

Answer (score 5):

@Joonas Ilmavirta treats "star" like an adjective. To me, "star" should be treated as a noun, in which case the translation becomes

> Bellum stellarum

(Disclaimer: I was raised to French & German translations of "Star Wars", where it is indeed translated as "war of the stars" -- bellum stellarum).

EDIT: based on the accepted answer, other candidates for a 'noun' translation include

> Bellum siderum

And in keeping with synonyms...

> Bellum astrorum

Comment: A. Debugne: "War of the Stars" could be interpreted as the stars are fighting each other. The adjectival thing--"starry" wars--giving the feeling that it's war in outer space.

Comment: @tony That kind of ambiguity is inevitable, I would say. Many languages use an official translation meaning "war of stars". I find adjectives to be more idiomatic than genitives in Latin, but a genitive is still a reasonable choice.

Comment: In French: La guerre des étoiles.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta That's a fair point -- on second thought, I agree that adjectives would be more natural here.

Comment: _Bellum Sidereum_ if we take the accepted answer into account?

Comment: @Cœur I've edited my post to add `sidereum` following your suggestion. I also added `astrorum` (because this discussion reminded me of `sic itur ad astra`), although it's unpleasant phonetically.

Answer (score 4):

I strongly disagree with C Monsour's interpretation of how the *-ārius* suffix works semantically. *Stēllārius* can perfectly mean 'of the stars', it is not tied to a singular interpretation ('of a star'). *Sīdereus* does have the advantage of being a classical word, used by many ancient authors even, much unlike *stēllārius* which isn't even medieval but modern, but this *argūmentum ad antīquitātem* is different from the grammatical-semantic argument.

Compare *librāria taberna* 'bookshop' (attested in Cicero, *Philippicae* II.21), in which many *librī* 'books, scrolls' are found, not just one. Or *herba pūlicāria* 'flea plant', from which fleas were believed to be born from (att. in Caelius Aurelianus, *Acūtae Passiōnēs* II).

Furthermore, the Favre edition (in the 1880s) of the Du Cange Medieval Latin dictionary mentions a noun *stēllāria* meaning 'a sea ship, or road in the sea or sky that guides sailors', something that naturally requires more than one star (in fact, there were and are more than a hundred commonly-used navigation stars, it's not just Polaris a.k.a. the North Star).

(Interestingly, *stēllārius* is also listed in the Favrean Du Cange as an adjective meaning *marīnus* 'of the sea', in association to ships guided by the stars at sea, and also *purpureus* 'purple', due to purple colorants being highly valued goods traded by sea.)

In conclusion, *bella stēllāria* is fine as long as you don't mind modern coinages. Since Latin users today prefer not to use novel words when possible (making only reasonable and convenient exceptions like *computātrum* 'computer'), *I agree bella sīderea is better*, but only on the grounds of ancient usage, not on the grounds of meaning.

**EDIT:** *Stēllāria* can also be interpreted as the neuter plural form of *stēllāris*, as both the suffix -ārius and the suffix -āris become -āria in the neuter plural (and *bella* 'wars' is a neuter plural noun, singular *bellum*).

*Stēllāris* is another non-classical, non-ancient word with some usage in medieval and modern Latin. The Lewis & Short dictionary lists one attestation in Macrobius (early 5th century), the OLD doesn't bother. Use that coinage if you want, but what I said about *sīdereus* being better due to its classical origin stands.

Comment: Welcome to the site and many thanks for an excellent first answer!

Comment: Is it *stellarius* or [*stellaris*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dstellaris)? I'm seeing both when I look!

Comment: I think you misunderstood my post.  I made no comment on the semantics of the suffix, but on the semantics of the root noun *stella* contrasted with the root noun *sidus*, which conveys the intended meaning.

Comment: @brianpck Oh, right, I forgot about *stēllāris*. *Bella* 'wars' is a neuter plural noun, and both the -ārius and the -āris suffix become -āria in the neuter plural. I have updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: @CMonsour Alright, I wrongly assumed you were saying that. By the way, interestingly the OLD says the classical but not that-well-regarded poet Hyginus uses the word *stēlla* with the meaning 'constellation' in a couple verses of his work.

Answer (score 2):

As an Italian let me exercise my direct descendant rights by saying that "Bellum stellarium" sounds really ugly, "Bellum sidereum" has a much better feeling to it. And why not take the extra step and -thinking at the title of a movie- go for *De bellis sidereis* after Caesar's well know prequel.

Comment: *De Bellis Sidereis* has a nice ring to it, but the historical echo might fit the movies better if they had been written from an imperial rather than a rebel point of view!